# Snapshot has not have Data in Bloc

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, bloc

I am trying to learn Bloc with creating dynamic simple theme manager. I create a class called `theme_bloc` :

```
class DefaultApi {
  final String name;
  final ThemeData theme;

  DefaultApi(this.name, this.theme);
}

class ThemeBloc {
  DefaultApi _defualt;

  ThemeBloc() {}

  final _themeManager = StreamController<DefaultApi>.broadcast();

  Stream<DefaultApi> get themeManager => _themeManager.stream;
  Function(DefaultApi) get changeTheme => _themeManager.sink.add;

  DefaultApi initialTheme() {
    _defualt = DefaultApi("light", ThemeManager.instance.lightTheme);
    return _defualt;

  }

  void dispose() {
    _themeManager.close();
  }
}
```

to inject bloc class i use provider like this:

```
class ThemeProvider with ChangeNotifier{
 ThemeBloc _bloc;

ThemeProvider(){
  _bloc = ThemeBloc();
}
ThemeBloc get bloc => _bloc;
}
```

I use `StringBuilder` in `main` class to set theme like this:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
      value: ThemeProvider(),
      child: Consumer<ThemeProvider>(
        builder: (crx, provider, child) {
          return StreamBuilder(
              initialData: provider.bloc.initialTheme(),
              stream: provider.bloc.themeManager,
              builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<DefaultApi>snapshot) {
                return snapshot.hasData? MaterialApp(
                  title: 'Flutter Demo',
                  theme: snapshot.data.theme,
                  home: HomePage(),
                ):Container();
              });
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```

In `HomePage` page i have switch to change theme between light and dark theme.

```
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final bloc = Provider.of<ThemeProvider>(context).bloc;
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Theme manager"),
      ),
      body: StreamBuilder<DefaultApi>(
          stream: bloc.themeManager,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return Switch(
                value: true,
                onChanged: (bool value) {
                },
              );
            } else if (!snapshot.hasData) {
              return Text("loading");
            }
            return Text("!!!!");
          }),
    );
  }
```

But after running just **loading** is printed into screen.

[image]

Someone know what is my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem will solve if the `StreamBuilder` widget inside `HomePage` have `initialData`. like this:

```dart
...
body: StreamBuilder<DefaultApi>(
          initialData: bloc.initialTheme(), // <<< new line 
          stream: bloc.themeManager,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
...
```

This input is not `required`. Yet I don't have any clue why it's absence cause problem here.

There are few deeper considerations:

### 1. Using ChangeNotifierProvider

As the [documentation](https://pub.dev/documentation/provider/latest/provider/ChangeNotifierProvider-class.html) recommends, use `ChangeNotifierProvider` instead of `ChangeNotifierProvider.value`. Obviously because you're creating a new instance

```dart
...
    return ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (_) => ThemeProvider(),
      child: Consumer<ThemeProvider>(
...
```

### 2. Prevent useless listening

Based on [this guide](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple#providerof), if you are using provider to only call actions, you have to use `listen: false` to prevent useless rebuilds.